# Formatting new identical HDDs, one taking way longer

Tags: hard-drive, formatting, storage, hard-drive-failure, data-loss-prevention

I have recently purchased 2 identical HDDs:

- Model Family: Seagate BarraCuda 3.5
- Device Model: ST4000DM004-2U9104 (labeled as ST4000DMZ04)
- Capacity: 4.00 TB [3.64 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes]

I've decided to test them a bit before using them in order to determine if there are any issues. What I did/intend to do:

1. SMART Conveyance test
2. SMART Short test
3. Run "format /fs:NTFS /p:2"
4. SMART Extended test

The issue I ran into is that the 3rd point is taking way longer on one of the drives. I ran the command for both of them roughly at the same time (~8PM). I checked the progress before going to bed (~11:30PM) - one was at 43%, and the other one - 14%. I left it overnight, and after ~12 hours, the 1st one had completed (not sure how long it took exactly), but the 2nd one was still at 53%.

I terminated the process and started it again in the hopes of getting a different result, but in about 1 hour it's only 5% done, so it looks like it's not going to be faster.

What could be the reason for this? Should I be worried and just return the drive?

**UPDATE:** Based on [user1686](https://superuser.com/users/1686/user1686)'s [comment](https://superuser.com/a/1781098/1793342), I've decided to return both disks and buy CMR/PMR disks instead of SMR.

---

##### smartctl output for the 1st/faster/reference disk

```
smartctl 7.2 2020-12-30 r5155 [x86_64-w64-mingw32-w10-b19045] (sf-7.2-1)
Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Seagate BarraCuda 3.5
Device Model:     ST4000DM004-2U9104
Serial Number:    ZFN4MGYT
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 0e6c2b651
Firmware Version: 0001
User Capacity:    4 000 787 030 016 bytes [4.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Form Factor:      3.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 5
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Thu Apr 27 10:38:53 2023 WEDT
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled
AAM feature is:   Unavailable
APM feature is:   Unavailable
Rd look-ahead is: Enabled
Write cache is:   Enabled
DSN feature is:   Unavailable
ATA Security is:  Disabled, frozen [SEC2]

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (  24) The self-test routine was aborted by
                    the host.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (    0) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x73) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    No Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 477) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x30a5) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAGS    VALUE WORST THRESH FAIL RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     POSR--   083   075   006    -    186126602
  3 Spin_Up_Time            PO----   097   097   000    -    0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        -O--CK   100   100   020    -    7
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   PO--CK   100   100   010    -    0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         POSR--   064   060   045    -    2776423
  9 Power_On_Hours          -O--CK   100   100   000    -    14 (154 171 0)
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        PO--C-   100   100   097    -    0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       -O--CK   100   100   020    -    1
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       -O--CK   100   100   000    -    0
184 End-to-End_Error        -O--CK   100   100   099    -    0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      -O--CK   100   100   000    -    0
188 Command_Timeout         -O--CK   100   100   000    -    0 0 0
189 High_Fly_Writes         -O-RCK   100   100   000    -    0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel -O---K   065   063   040    -    35 (Min/Max 25/37)
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      -O--CK   100   100   000    -    0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count -O--CK   100   100   000    -    1
193 Load_Cycle_Count        -O--CK   100   100   000    -    17
194 Temperature_Celsius     -O---K   035   040   000    -    35 (0 25 0 0 0)
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  -O-RC-   083   075   000    -    186126602
197 Current_Pending_Sector  -O--C-   100   100   000    -    0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   ----C-   100   100   000    -    0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    -OSRCK   200   200   000    -    0
240 Head_Flying_Hours       ------   100   253   000    -    11h+30m+45.764s
241 Total_LBAs_Written      ------   100   253   000    -    7814419344
242 Total_LBAs_Read         ------   100   253   000    -    241092
                            ||||||_ K auto-keep
                            |||||__ C event count
                            ||||___ R error rate
                            |||____ S speed/performance
                            ||_____ O updated online
                            |______ P prefailure warning

General Purpose Log Directory Version 1
SMART           Log Directory Version 1 [multi-sector log support]
Address    Access  R/W   Size  Description
0x00       GPL,SL  R/O      1  Log Directory
0x01           SL  R/O      1  Summary SMART error log
0x02           SL  R/O      5  Comprehensive SMART error log
0x03       GPL     R/O      5  Ext. Comprehensive SMART error log
0x04       GPL,SL  R/O      8  Device Statistics log
0x06           SL  R/O      1  SMART self-test log
0x07       GPL     R/O      1  Extended self-test log
0x08       GPL     R/O      2  Power Conditions log
0x09           SL  R/W      1  Selective self-test log
0x0c       GPL     R/O   2048  Pending Defects log
0x10       GPL     R/O      1  NCQ Command Error log
0x11       GPL     R/O      1  SATA Phy Event Counters log
0x21       GPL     R/O      1  Write stream error log
0x22       GPL     R/O      1  Read stream error log
0x24       GPL     R/O    512  Current Device Internal Status Data log
0x30       GPL,SL  R/O      9  IDENTIFY DEVICE data log
0x80-0x9f  GPL,SL  R/W     16  Host vendor specific log
0xa1       GPL,SL  VS      24  Device vendor specific log
0xa2       GPL     VS    8160  Device vendor specific log
0xa8-0xa9  GPL,SL  VS     136  Device vendor specific log
0xab       GPL     VS       1  Device vendor specific log
0xb0       GPL     VS    9048  Device vendor specific log
0xbe-0xbf  GPL     VS   65535  Device vendor specific log
0xc0       GPL,SL  VS       1  Device vendor specific log
0xc1       GPL,SL  VS      16  Device vendor specific log
0xc3       GPL,SL  VS       8  Device vendor specific log
0xc4       GPL,SL  VS      24  Device vendor specific log
0xd1       GPL     VS     264  Device vendor specific log
0xd3       GPL     VS    1920  Device vendor specific log
0xe0       GPL,SL  R/W      1  SCT Command/Status
0xe1       GPL,SL  R/W      1  SCT Data Transfer

SMART Extended Comprehensive Error Log Version: 1 (5 sectors)
No Errors Logged

SMART Extended Self-test Log Version: 1 (1 sectors)
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Aborted by host               80%        14         -
# 2  Extended offline    Aborted by host               90%        13         -
# 3  Short offline       Completed without error       00%         0         -
# 4  Conveyance offline  Completed without error       00%         0         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.

SCT Status Version:                  3
SCT Version (vendor specific):       522 (0x020a)
Device State:                        Active (0)
Current Temperature:                    35 Celsius
Power Cycle Min/Max Temperature:     25/37 Celsius
Lifetime    Min/Max Temperature:     25/37 Celsius
Under/Over Temperature Limit Count:   0/0

SCT Temperature History Version:     2
Temperature Sampling Period:         3 minutes
Temperature Logging Interval:        59 minutes
Min/Max recommended Temperature:     14/55 Celsius
Min/Max Temperature Limit:           10/60 Celsius
Temperature History Size (Index):    128 (16)

Index    Estimated Time   Temperature Celsius
  17    2023-04-22 05:21     ?  -
 ...    ..(109 skipped).    ..  -
 127    2023-04-26 17:31     ?  -
   0    2023-04-26 18:30    28  *********
   1    2023-04-26 19:29     ?  -
   2    2023-04-26 20:28    27  ********
   3    2023-04-26 21:27    36  *****************
   4    2023-04-26 22:26    37  ******************
   5    2023-04-26 23:25    36  *****************
   6    2023-04-27 00:24    35  ****************
   7    2023-04-27 01:23    35  ****************
   8    2023-04-27 02:22    34  ***************
   9    2023-04-27 03:21    34  ***************
  10    2023-04-27 04:20    33  **************
  11    2023-04-27 05:19    30  ***********
  12    2023-04-27 06:18    25  ******
  13    2023-04-27 07:17    27  ********
  14    2023-04-27 08:16    32  *************
  15    2023-04-27 09:15    35  ****************
  16    2023-04-27 10:14    35  ****************

SCT Error Recovery Control command not supported

Device Statistics (GP Log 0x04)
Page  Offset Size        Value Flags Description
0x01  =====  =               =  ===  == General Statistics (rev 1) ==
0x01  0x008  4               1  ---  Lifetime Power-On Resets
0x01  0x010  4              14  ---  Power-on Hours
0x01  0x018  6      7814419344  ---  Logical Sectors Written
0x01  0x020  6        30525155  ---  Number of Write Commands
0x01  0x028  6          241092  ---  Logical Sectors Read
0x01  0x030  6            1571  ---  Number of Read Commands
0x01  0x038  6   1682252607001  ---  Date and Time TimeStamp
0x03  =====  =               =  ===  == Rotating Media Statistics (rev 1) ==
0x03  0x008  4              12  ---  Spindle Motor Power-on Hours
0x03  0x010  4              11  ---  Head Flying Hours
0x03  0x018  4              17  ---  Head Load Events
0x03  0x020  4               0  ---  Number of Reallocated Logical Sectors
0x03  0x028  4               0  ---  Read Recovery Attempts
0x03  0x030  4               0  ---  Number of Mechanical Start Failures
0x03  0x038  4               0  ---  Number of Realloc. Candidate Logical Sectors
0x03  0x040  4               1  ---  Number of High Priority Unload Events
0x04  =====  =               =  ===  == General Errors Statistics (rev 1) ==
0x04  0x008  4               0  ---  Number of Reported Uncorrectable Errors
0x04  0x010  4               0  ---  Resets Between Cmd Acceptance and Completion
0x05  =====  =               =  ===  == Temperature Statistics (rev 1) ==
0x05  0x008  1              35  ---  Current Temperature
0x05  0x010  1               -  ---  Average Short Term Temperature
0x05  0x018  1               -  ---  Average Long Term Temperature
0x05  0x020  1              37  ---  Highest Temperature
0x05  0x028  1              25  ---  Lowest Temperature
0x05  0x030  1               -  ---  Highest Average Short Term Temperature
0x05  0x038  1               -  ---  Lowest Average Short Term Temperature
0x05  0x040  1               -  ---  Highest Average Long Term Temperature
0x05  0x048  1               -  ---  Lowest Average Long Term Temperature
0x05  0x050  4               0  ---  Time in Over-Temperature
0x05  0x058  1              60  ---  Specified Maximum Operating Temperature
0x05  0x060  4               0  ---  Time in Under-Temperature
0x05  0x068  1               0  ---  Specified Minimum Operating Temperature
0x06  =====  =               =  ===  == Transport Statistics (rev 1) ==
0x06  0x008  4               8  ---  Number of Hardware Resets
0x06  0x010  4               1  ---  Number of ASR Events
0x06  0x018  4               0  ---  Number of Interface CRC Errors
                                |||_ C monitored condition met
                                ||__ D supports DSN
                                |___ N normalized value

SATA Phy Event Counters (GP Log 0x11)
ID      Size     Value  Description
0x000a  2            8  Device-to-host register FISes sent due to a COMRESET
0x0001  2            0  Command failed due to ICRC error
0x0003  2            0  R_ERR response for device-to-host data FIS
0x0004  2            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device data FIS
0x0006  2            0  R_ERR response for device-to-host non-data FIS
0x0007  2            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device non-data FIS
```

##### smartctl output for the 2nd/slower disk

```
smartctl 7.2 2020-12-30 r5155 [x86_64-w64-mingw32-w10-b19045] (sf-7.2-1)
Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Seagate BarraCuda 3.5
Device Model:     ST4000DM004-2U9104
Serial Number:    ZFN4MH0Y
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 0e6c2b3f4
Firmware Version: 0001
User Capacity:    4 000 787 030 016 bytes [4.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Form Factor:      3.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 5
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Thu Apr 27 09:09:43 2023 WEDT
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled
AAM feature is:   Unavailable
APM feature is:   Unavailable
Rd look-ahead is: Enabled
Write cache is:   Enabled
DSN feature is:   Unavailable
ATA Security is:  Disabled, frozen [SEC2]

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (    0) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x73) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    No Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 481) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x30a5) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAGS    VALUE WORST THRESH FAIL RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     POSR--   082   064   006    -    152739840
  3 Spin_Up_Time            PO----   100   100   000    -    0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        -O--CK   100   100   020    -    1
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   PO--CK   100   100   010    -    0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         POSR--   066   060   045    -    3635618
  9 Power_On_Hours          -O--CK   100   100   000    -    12 (217 18 0)
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        PO--C-   100   100   097    -    0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       -O--CK   100   100   020    -    1
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       -O--CK   100   100   000    -    0
184 End-to-End_Error        -O--CK   100   100   099    -    0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      -O--CK   100   100   000    -    0
188 Command_Timeout         -O--CK   100   100   000    -    0 0 0
189 High_Fly_Writes         -O-RCK   100   100   000    -    0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel -O---K   063   062   040    -    37 (Min/Max 27/38)
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      -O--CK   100   100   000    -    0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count -O--CK   100   100   000    -    1
193 Load_Cycle_Count        -O--CK   100   100   000    -    2
194 Temperature_Celsius     -O---K   037   040   000    -    37 (0 27 0 0 0)
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  -O-RC-   082   064   000    -    152739840
197 Current_Pending_Sector  -O--C-   100   100   000    -    0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   ----C-   100   100   000    -    0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    -OSRCK   200   200   000    -    0
240 Head_Flying_Hours       ------   100   253   000    -    12h+46m+01.441s
241 Total_LBAs_Written      ------   100   253   000    -    13784375564
242 Total_LBAs_Read         ------   100   253   000    -    1949
                            ||||||_ K auto-keep
                            |||||__ C event count
                            ||||___ R error rate
                            |||____ S speed/performance
                            ||_____ O updated online
                            |______ P prefailure warning

General Purpose Log Directory Version 1
SMART           Log Directory Version 1 [multi-sector log support]
Address    Access  R/W   Size  Description
0x00       GPL,SL  R/O      1  Log Directory
0x01           SL  R/O      1  Summary SMART error log
0x02           SL  R/O      5  Comprehensive SMART error log
0x03       GPL     R/O      5  Ext. Comprehensive SMART error log
0x04       GPL,SL  R/O      8  Device Statistics log
0x06           SL  R/O      1  SMART self-test log
0x07       GPL     R/O      1  Extended self-test log
0x08       GPL     R/O      2  Power Conditions log
0x09           SL  R/W      1  Selective self-test log
0x0c       GPL     R/O   2048  Pending Defects log
0x10       GPL     R/O      1  NCQ Command Error log
0x11       GPL     R/O      1  SATA Phy Event Counters log
0x21       GPL     R/O      1  Write stream error log
0x22       GPL     R/O      1  Read stream error log
0x24       GPL     R/O    512  Current Device Internal Status Data log
0x30       GPL,SL  R/O      9  IDENTIFY DEVICE data log
0x80-0x9f  GPL,SL  R/W     16  Host vendor specific log
0xa1       GPL,SL  VS      24  Device vendor specific log
0xa2       GPL     VS    8160  Device vendor specific log
0xa8-0xa9  GPL,SL  VS     136  Device vendor specific log
0xab       GPL     VS       1  Device vendor specific log
0xb0       GPL     VS    9048  Device vendor specific log
0xbe-0xbf  GPL     VS   65535  Device vendor specific log
0xc0       GPL,SL  VS       1  Device vendor specific log
0xc1       GPL,SL  VS      16  Device vendor specific log
0xc3       GPL,SL  VS       8  Device vendor specific log
0xc4       GPL,SL  VS      24  Device vendor specific log
0xd1       GPL     VS     264  Device vendor specific log
0xd3       GPL     VS    1920  Device vendor specific log
0xe0       GPL,SL  R/W      1  SCT Command/Status
0xe1       GPL,SL  R/W      1  SCT Data Transfer

SMART Extended Comprehensive Error Log Version: 1 (5 sectors)
No Errors Logged

SMART Extended Self-test Log Version: 1 (1 sectors)
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%         0         -
# 2  Conveyance offline  Completed without error       00%         0         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.

SCT Status Version:                  3
SCT Version (vendor specific):       522 (0x020a)
Device State:                        Active (0)
Current Temperature:                    37 Celsius
Power Cycle Min/Max Temperature:     27/38 Celsius
Lifetime    Min/Max Temperature:     27/38 Celsius
Under/Over Temperature Limit Count:   0/0

SCT Temperature History Version:     2
Temperature Sampling Period:         3 minutes
Temperature Logging Interval:        59 minutes
Min/Max recommended Temperature:     14/55 Celsius
Min/Max Temperature Limit:           10/60 Celsius
Temperature History Size (Index):    128 (14)

Index    Estimated Time   Temperature Celsius
  15    2023-04-22 03:23     ?  -
 ...    ..(111 skipped).    ..  -
 127    2023-04-26 17:31     ?  -
   0    2023-04-26 18:30    27  ********
   1    2023-04-26 19:29     ?  -
   2    2023-04-26 20:28    27  ********
   3    2023-04-26 21:27    37  ******************
   4    2023-04-26 22:26    38  *******************
   5    2023-04-26 23:25    37  ******************
   6    2023-04-27 00:24    36  *****************
   7    2023-04-27 01:23    36  *****************
   8    2023-04-27 02:22    35  ****************
 ...    ..(  2 skipped).    ..  ****************
  11    2023-04-27 05:19    35  ****************
  12    2023-04-27 06:18    34  ***************
  13    2023-04-27 07:17    36  *****************
  14    2023-04-27 08:16    37  ******************

SCT Error Recovery Control command not supported

Device Statistics (GP Log 0x04)
Page  Offset Size        Value Flags Description
0x01  =====  =               =  ===  == General Statistics (rev 1) ==
0x01  0x008  4               1  ---  Lifetime Power-On Resets
0x01  0x010  4              12  ---  Power-on Hours
0x01  0x018  6     13784402188  ---  Logical Sectors Written
0x01  0x020  6        53845332  ---  Number of Write Commands
0x01  0x028  6            1949  ---  Logical Sectors Read
0x01  0x030  6             587  ---  Number of Read Commands
0x01  0x038  6   1682298586055  ---  Date and Time TimeStamp
0x03  =====  =               =  ===  == Rotating Media Statistics (rev 1) ==
0x03  0x008  4              12  ---  Spindle Motor Power-on Hours
0x03  0x010  4              12  ---  Head Flying Hours
0x03  0x018  4               2  ---  Head Load Events
0x03  0x020  4               0  ---  Number of Reallocated Logical Sectors
0x03  0x028  4               0  ---  Read Recovery Attempts
0x03  0x030  4               0  ---  Number of Mechanical Start Failures
0x03  0x038  4               0  ---  Number of Realloc. Candidate Logical Sectors
0x03  0x040  4               1  ---  Number of High Priority Unload Events
0x04  =====  =               =  ===  == General Errors Statistics (rev 1) ==
0x04  0x008  4               0  ---  Number of Reported Uncorrectable Errors
0x04  0x010  4               0  ---  Resets Between Cmd Acceptance and Completion
0x05  =====  =               =  ===  == Temperature Statistics (rev 1) ==
0x05  0x008  1              37  ---  Current Temperature
0x05  0x010  1               -  ---  Average Short Term Temperature
0x05  0x018  1               -  ---  Average Long Term Temperature
0x05  0x020  1              38  ---  Highest Temperature
0x05  0x028  1              27  ---  Lowest Temperature
0x05  0x030  1               -  ---  Highest Average Short Term Temperature
0x05  0x038  1               -  ---  Lowest Average Short Term Temperature
0x05  0x040  1               -  ---  Highest Average Long Term Temperature
0x05  0x048  1               -  ---  Lowest Average Long Term Temperature
0x05  0x050  4               0  ---  Time in Over-Temperature
0x05  0x058  1              60  ---  Specified Maximum Operating Temperature
0x05  0x060  4               0  ---  Time in Under-Temperature
0x05  0x068  1               0  ---  Specified Minimum Operating Temperature
0x06  =====  =               =  ===  == Transport Statistics (rev 1) ==
0x06  0x008  4               2  ---  Number of Hardware Resets
0x06  0x010  4               1  ---  Number of ASR Events
0x06  0x018  4               0  ---  Number of Interface CRC Errors
                                |||_ C monitored condition met
                                ||__ D supports DSN
                                |___ N normalized value

SATA Phy Event Counters (GP Log 0x11)
ID      Size     Value  Description
0x000a  2            2  Device-to-host register FISes sent due to a COMRESET
0x0001  2            0  Command failed due to ICRC error
0x0003  2            0  R_ERR response for device-to-host data FIS
0x0004  2            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device data FIS
0x0006  2            0  R_ERR response for device-to-host non-data FIS
0x0007  2            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device non-data FIS
```

Comment: Have you `chkdsk`-ed / `fsck`-ed em? It is theoretically possible one got damaged during shipping.

Comment: How are the drives connected? Are they connected to two different motherboards? Or with different cables/adapters etc.? Have you tried to test them by connecting one by one to exactly the same configuration of other components?

Comment: @Gantendo I have not used `chkdsk` (or `fsck`; on Windows 10, but could use WSL if needed). I was under the impression that formatting and using the extended SMART test would be sufficient.

@KamilMaciorowski the drives are both connected to the same motherboard, using the same type of cables, and both are connected to the same power supply. What I'm considering is switching their cables and checking again.

Comment: Looking at SMART is always wise in such cases, can you add it to OP so we can compare?

Comment: Thanks, @JoepvanSteen! Added!

Comment: No brand new drive should have 152 million Hardware_ECC_Recovered sectors.  Are you sure this isn't some kind of refurb drive?

Comment: @cybernard they were sold to me by Amazon directly as new, so I doubt they are refurbished. It's likely reporting wrong.

Comment: re-run SMART and tell me if the hardware ECC corrections have increased or stated the same.

Comment: @cybernard the numbers are actually smaller now... For the 1st disk it changed from 186126602 to 136312752, and from 152739840 to 35753008 on the 2nd.

Comment: That is concerning, it maybe that they are increasing so quickly that they roll over to 0 and start over.  I have had that happen before.  Try it again, but only wait 1 minute between run #1 and run #2 and see if the number increase.

Comment: This is a Seagate, those aren't perse errors, see https://www.disktuna.com/big-scary-raw-s-m-a-r-t-values-arent-always-bad-news/. ECC errors decoded, 152739840 =  0x091AA000 so 152739840 reads, 0 errors, see document linked to in blog.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen  The document you provided show instructions how to decode  "Attribute ID 188: Command Timeout Count"  and "Attribute ID 7: Seek Error Rate".  So you are applying those rules to a completely different attribute, the ECC attributes "195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered", when the article doesn't cover that attribute.

Comment: @cybernard No I am not, my blog gives just one or two examples. And yes, attribute 195 os covered by the document referred to in the article and I used it to decode 152739840: 
Raw [3 – 0] = Number of Sector reads
Raw [6 - 4] = Number of ECC OTF errors .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ST4000DM004 is an SMR disk – its internal storage is not linear, but firmware-managed much like on SSDs (as the overlapped SMR layout makes it impossible to update sectors in-place).

With SMR (and with SSDs), even though your writes intend to replace the existing logical sectors, they nevertheless get redirected to new physical zones/areas at first, with old data only being overwritten only later during the disk's idle maintenance – until the amount of new data causes the disk to run out of usable space, in which case it needs to perform internal reshuffling in a hurry.

Instead of zeroing via `/p:` or other tools that do regular writes, perform an ATA Secure Erase on the disk if possible, and/or issue TRIM commands (discards) using `blkdiscard`. (You might need a Linux box and a USB-SATA adapter for this.)

Comment: Zeroing (and secure erase) are both kinda pointless considering the drives are new; I doubt the Seagate factory used them to store their linux distros.

Comment: As far as I understand, the idea behind the testing approach I chose is to supposedly engage all sectors and cause any bad sectors to be reallocated, which should show during the extended SMART test. If there are (m)any, it might be better to return the drive.

@user1686 would the ATA Secure Erase achieve the same result I'm trying to get with the "format"?

Comment: I'd expect it to; with HDDs, the whole purpose of ATA Secure Erase is to have the disk wipe data from every sector (if not in regular erase then at least in "Enhanced" mode). It has caught a few bad sectors and dying disks for me when repurposing used disks.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like either the disks are not really identical, or that the
second one is bad.

The simplest solution would be to use the warranty and ask for
a replacement disk.

(I'm not saying it's your case, but once I had a bad disk that was
manifestly already used. It was probably replaced/stolen at the factory
or at the vendor.)